# getting first ten links from fox news using beautiful soup

Tags: python, html, beautifulsoup, python-requests

I am having trouble using Beautiful Soup to get the links from fox news I dont think i have the html code understode enough to get how to extract the data.

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup


r = requests.get("http://www.foxnews.com/trending/#world")
data = BeautifulSoup(r.content).find("div",{"class":"module articles"}).find("div",{"class":"list"}).find_all("div",{"id":"id_"})
links = [d.a["href"] for d in data[:10]]
```

Data shows up as an empty list so i don't think i'm looking at the right section of html. Any help would be great.
Swiss

Comment: it's because of the last `.find_all("div",{"id":"id_"})`

Comment: but the links to the top stories are all in <div id="id_blahblah"> where blahbah is unique to each story title

Comment: Don't try to do so many operations at once and you will find your problem. Also, your code will be easier to read.
So do something like:
`soup = BeautifulSoup(r.content)` and
`articles = soup.find("div",{"class":"module articles"})` . Then go from there.